# What is the correct way to implement gradient accumulation in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Broadly there are two ways:

1. Call `loss.backward()` on every batch, but only call `optimizer.step()` and `optimizer.zero_grad()` every N batches. Is it the case that the gradients of the N batches are **summed up**? Hence to maintain the same **learning rate per effective batch**, we have to **divide** the learning rate by N?
2. Accumulate **loss** instead of gradient, and call `(loss / N).backward()` every N batches. This is easy to understand, but does it defeat the purpose of saving memory (because the gradients of the N batches are computed at once)? The learning rate doesn't need adjusting to maintain the same learning rate per effective batch, but should be **multiplied** by N if you want to maintain the same learning rate per example.

Which one is better, or more commonly used in packages such as pytorch-lightning? It seems that `optimizer.zero_grad()` is a prefect fit for gradient accumulation, therefore (1) should be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PytorchLightning and you get this feature of the box, see the Trainer argument `accumulate_grad_batches` which you can also pair with `gradient_clip_val`, more in [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/training_tricks.html#accumulate-gradients).

Answer (score 1):

**The correct way is option 1**: do everything as normal, but only call `opt.zero_grad()` and `opt.step()` every N batches.

The reason is that with option two (summing the losses), you are building one computation graph for the whole summed loss, including all N forwards. This does not save memory. In fact, it probably costs more memory than just combining the N microbatches into a single batch.

The reason that option 1 saves memory is that if pytorch is computing gradients and it finds some gradients already there, it just adds the new gradients to the old. That means that after the `N` steps, the gradients you've computed are the sums of the gradients of all the microbatches.

If you are summing your loss, then these are the exact gradients you would get if you combined all `N` microbatches into a single batch, and ran it through the model. If you are averaging your loss over the instances in the batch, you should correct for this. The easiest is to switch to a summed loss, and multiply your learning rate by `1/(B*N)`, where `B` is the size of the microbatches.

Note that certain operations might ruin the equivalense. For instance, if you have a batch normalization, then the gradient accumulation version normalizes over $B$ instances, where the plain version normalizes over `B*N` instances. If `B` is small, this may hurt performance. You can fix this particular issue by switching to Layer Normalization, but the larger message is that you need to think through your whole network to check that every part performs as expected under gradient accumulation.